# Does $g: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,y,z) \rightarrow \frac{f}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}$ reaches its max/min value

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, maxima-minima

Does $g: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,y,z) \rightarrow \frac{f}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}$ reaches her max/min value when we know that the function $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function that is also continuous.

I wanted to aproach this as the product of 2 functions $g=fh$ with $h=\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Because $h$ is continuous and bounded by $0<h\leq 1$: both functions will reach their minimum and maximum value. (According to the supremum theorem)

Is this a correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not correct.

Consider the following one-dimensional counterexample (which can be extended to functions $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ easily). Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the constant function $f(x)=1$ and let $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then $g$ does not have a minimum.

Comment: Can you give me a hint for the correct solution? Because I tried it with partial derivatives also but I could not conclude anything from this.

Comment: The correct solution is that you can't guarantee that $g$ attains a minimum or maximum in general. My example above yields a $g$ that does not have a minimum. The example of Kavi Rama Murthys answer shows that you can't guarantee a maximum either.

Comment: Do I a have to prove this with contradiction or is there a method for this?

Comment: I'm confused. You are asking how to prove that $g$ has extrema in general? You can't prove that because it's not true. I gave an example that shows that $g$ does not need to have a minimum. The other answer gives an example that shows that $g$ does not need to have a maximum. With these two examples you should be able to conjure up an example where $g$ has neither an minimum or maximum. That should put any statement to bed.

Comment: No I meant if I had to prove that g does not have a max/min by stating that it has one and then becoming a contradiction. But i realize now that if I have a counterexample that that is enough to prove that this is not the case. So thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For some $f$ the maximum is attained, for others is is not attained. $f \equiv 0$ is an obvious example where the maximum is attained. Now let $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}} {1+x^{2}}$. Then the supremum is $1$ but it is never attained.

[ $\frac {x^{2}} {1+x^{2}} \frac  1{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}=1$ implies that each of the factors equals $1$ but $\frac {x^{2}} {1+x^{2}}$ cannot be equal to $1$].